# Error with C++ Maps erase

Tags: c++, dictionary

I had to delete some of the entries from c++ `std::map`, for that purpose I iterate over the `std::map` and used erase. But I get an error. The error is like :

```
0x0017f3f6 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase () from /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0017f3f6 in std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase () from /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00487ef4 in getLetters () from /usr/lib/libmail.so
#2  0x0048cacc in getHeader () from /usr/lib/libmail.so

#6  0x08048802 in __gxx_personality_v0 ()
#7  0x00251e9c in __libc_start_main () from /lib/libc.so.6
#8  0x080486a1 in __gxx_personality_v0 ()
(gdb)
```

The code was something like this:

```
int nlsize=LettersMap.size();

if(nlsize > MAXNL)              
{                               
        std::map <std::string,MSG_HEADER>::iterator it;
        int i=0;                
        for( i=0, it=LettersMap.begin();  i <nlsize-MAXNL  ;i++, it++)
        {                       
                LettersMap.erase(it);                 
        }                       
}
```

Can someone please point out the error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with std::map::iterator after calling erase()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636182/problem-with-stdmapiterator-after-calling-erase)

Comment: That's a somewhat unusual way to use a `set`. Perhaps you should double-check whether it's really the right type of container.

Comment: @KerrekSB: `set`? Where do you see a `set`? Been up too late, have you?

Comment: @Als: Oh, sorry. Map, set, same thing... Too drunk to post clearly, I better shut up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int n = nlsize - MAXNL;
while (n-- > 0) {
    LettersMap.erase(LettersMap.begin());
}
```

The iterator `it` is becoming instable by `erase`.

Comment: You probably meant *Invalidated*.

Comment: Yes _invalidated_ is the term used in the C++ STL reference. I found that too harmless for having things pointing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You have an `iterator` to the `std::map`, right? In your `for` loop, you initialize your `iterator` to the beginning. You check if it is within bounds. You then `erase` the `iterator`. Your `iterator` is now invalid. The `iterator`s are effectively like pointers and when you `erase`, you are effectively `delete`ing a value that was "pointed" to. As such, other `iterator`s can't guarantee that they point to something valid.

Specifically, you `erase`, causing an invalidation of your `iterator`. A guaranteed one, because it's the `iterator` you `erase`d. You need a new `iterator`, preferably one right after where you `erase`d, right? Unfortunately, `std::map` does not offer that functionality. `std::map` isn't really intended to be treated as a sequential container. The idea is that you access values by their key, not their position. Seeing as you're trying to erase by their sequential order, this is problematic.

Instead, perhaps, you could identify which key you need to erase based on `i`? Then use `find` to find the key and `erase` to erase the key. Since you are no longer sequentially iterating through your `std::map`, you no longer have to worry about invalidated `iterator`s.

Comment: This or, y'know, use the appropriate container for whatever it is you're storing. It kind of sounds like `std::map` might not be the right tool for the job.