# Bad Acces Memory with map iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with std::map::iterator after calling erase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636182/problem-with-stdmapiterator-after-calling-erase)

May be you could enlighten me with an issue I'm currently having.
So problem is that I get a bad access memory when I'm trying to erase some elements in the map.
We suppose the following typedef :

```
typedef std::map < std::string *, Document *, pStringCompare > Map;
```

And we suppose we already have instantiated a map which contains two elements (for example) before the execution of all the following code. 
This code with working great :

```
Map::iterator it = documents.begin();

std::string *s = it->first;
Document *d = it->second;

documents.erase(it);

delete d;
delete s;
```

But when I'm trying to loop with the iterator, i get the error.

```
for (Map::iterator it = documents.begin() ; it != documents.end() ; it++)
{
    std::string s = * ( it->first);
    Document dd = * (it->second);
    std::cout << s << " || " << dd;
    documents.erase(it);  // This line causes the bad access memory error.
}
```

Thanks for your help ! It's really appreciated !

Aleks

Comment: Are you sure it's that line on which the error occurs? I'd expect it to occur on the increment (`it++`), because `it` becomes *invalid* after a call to `erase()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing invalidated iterator. Once you pass it to `erase()` it is no longer valid, so you cannot increment it in your `for` loop. See [Iterator Invalidation Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) for more details on that.

Your loop should be structured like this to avoid accessing invalidated iterators:

```
for (Map::iterator it = documents.begin() ; it != documents.end() ; )
{
    std::string s = * ( it->first);
    Document dd = * (it->second);
    std::cout << s << " || " << dd;
    documents.erase(it++);
}
```

Though I really recommend you read more documentation and understand what is going on here. For example, see [this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Conferences/Slides/CppInvalidIterators-DevConnections-2002.pdf).

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help and the doc, it's been very helpful  !

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
while ((Map::iterator iter = documents.begin()) != documents.end())
{
   std::string s = * ( iter->first);
   Document dd = * (iter->second);
   std::cout << s << " || " << dd;
   documents.erase(iter);
}
```