# c++ map erase function not working properly with iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I am removing the elements from map by using erase in the following way but it is not working properly. Why? It is not removing all.

```
float nw_cut=80.0;
for(it=nw_tot1.begin();it!=nw_tot1.end();it++)
{
    float f=(float) ((float) it->second/lines)*100.0;
    if ( f < nw_cut )
    {
        nw_tot1.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are similar questions e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636182/problem-with-stdmapiterator-after-calling-erase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`std::map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

If `erase(it)` is called then `it` is invalidated, and it is then used by the `for` loop causing undefined behaviour. Store the return value of `erase()`, which returns an iterator to the next element after the erased element (since c++11), and only increment if `erase()` was not called:

```
for(it = nw_tot1.begin(); it != nw_tot1.end();)
{
    float f=(float) ((float) it->second/lines)*100.0;

    if ( f < nw_cut ) it = nw_tot1.erase(it);
    else ++it;
}
```

In c++03 (and c++11 also) this could be accomplished with:

```
for(it = nw_tot1.begin(); it != nw_tot1.end();)
{
    float f=(float) ((float) it->second/lines)*100.0;

    if ( f < nw_cut ) nw_tot1.erase(it++);
    else ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
float nw_cut=80.0;
for(it=nw_tot1.begin();it!=nw_tot1.end();)
{
    float f=(float) ((float) it->second/lines)*100.0;
    it_temp = it;    //store it in temp variable because reference is invalidated when you use it in erase.
    ++it;
    if ( f < nw_cut ) {
        nw_tot1.erase(it_temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(it = nw_tot1.begin(); it != nw_tot1.end();)
{
    float f=(float) ((float) it->second/lines)*100.0;

    if ( f < nw_cut ) it = nw_tot1.erase(it);
    else ++it;
}
```