# When erase container iterator, can I just use iterator++?

Tags: c++, iterator, erase

```
for(; iter != endIter; ) {
     if (Some Condition) {
          iter = aMap.erase(iter);
     } else {
          ++iter;
     }
}

for(; iter != endIter; iter++) {
     if (Some Condition) {
          aMap.erase(iter);
     }
}
```

see code above, I wonder the difference between the two code style since sometimes the posterior one may induce error, for example, andriod build

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636214/4342498

Comment: Completely solved my question，thank you！