# Prime factorization of number error

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

I made a function that returns a `vector` with all the prime factors of an integer, and I am trying to make another function that creates a `map` from that `vector`.

However, I am getting some typicall illegal memory access error and I cannot find what it is. I think it happens inside the `for` loop of the `map<int, int> factorizacion(vector<int>)` function.

I hope I could get some help here.

I could post the whole program but I'll just stick to the function that's causing the issue. Just ask for the rest of the code in case you need to give it a look.

```
map<int, int> factorizacion(vector<int> v) {
    map<int, int> m;

    while (!v.empty()) {
        int elto = v.front();
        int ctd = 0;

        for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
            if (*it == elto) {
                ++ctd;
                v.erase(it);
            }
        }
        m[elto] = ctd;
    }

    return m;
}
```

Comment: Erasing from the vector makes your iterators invalid and leads to undefined behaviour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874441/deleting-elements-from-stl-set-while-iterating

Comment: The same thing can be achieved using `multiset(v.begin(),v.end())`, by the way, or by a simple `for (int x: v) m[x]++;`

Comment: @NiklasB. Worth mentioning that the enhanced for works only in C++11

Comment: @Boris: OP seems to know how to iterate over a vector even without range-based for loops, so he should be able to adapt it in case he decides to use an outdated compiler :)

Comment: actually I am kind of struggling with iteration now. is there any way to get the previous/next iterator of an iterator with C++98?

Comment: @dabadaba: For RandomIterator, you can use `+1` and `-1`, but I don't need that very often. Why do you think you need it? And more importantly, why do you use C++98? I mean, at least C++03 should be supported by every compiler by now

Comment: I get a compilation error when I try  `m.end()-1`. I just want to stop the printing loop before the last element so I don't get an extra plus sign. Yeah, it's C++03.

Comment: @dabadaba: Yeah, map iterators don't support random access obviously. You can just use the [example implementation from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) if you really want to. But I would rather do something like `bool first = 1; for (map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) { if (!first) cout << " + "; first = 0; cout << it->fst << "^" << it->snd; }` otherwise you need to duplicate the loop body. You should also consider using C++11 if you have the choice.

Comment: Or just `for (map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) { if (it != m.begin()) cout << " + "; cout << it->fst << "^" << it->snd; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You modify a collection you iterate upon:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == elto) {
        ++ctd;
        v.erase(it);
    }
}
```

If you erase the item pointed by the iterator you can not just continue using the same iterator.

Btw you can make use of the fact that `map` will automatically initialize to 0 a value for key that does not exist.

This code will do what you want:

```
map<int, int> m;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
  m[v[i]]++;
}
```

The only thing is that performance-wise my solution is a bit slower - it executes more queries than the optimal solution. However, the solution I propose is better that yours (when it gets fixed, because):

- Erasing in a vector is costly operation and takes linear time, a lot worse performance wise than my `map` tweak
- I do not alter the parameter of the method. I know it is not passed in by reference but it is always a good idea not to affect parameters when this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

`v.erase(it)` makes `it` invalid. You need to change your loop:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end();) {
    if (*it == elto) {
        ++ctd;
        it = v.erase(it);
    } else {
       ++it;
    }
}
```

Or better, use `std::remove` and `.erase` similarly to the "erase-remove" idiom. Which I won't repeat here because you can look it up. You can compute the count as the difference between two iterators.

Or even better, count the factors without erasing them at all, as in Niklas's comment.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. But can you explain why my program gave an error and why those changes need to be done?

Comment: @dabadaba: "`v.erase(it)` makes `it` invalid" is the explanation why your program is undefined and the proposed code sample in this answer contains the changes that need to be done.

Comment: oooh so `it` is somewhat flagged?

Comment: @dabadaba: [`vector::erase` "Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)