# delete an object both from vector and memory while iterating

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I trying to to delete an object both from a vector of objects and from memory using its destructor. I understood the deleting the the object that the iterator points to, is making the the iterator to point  to the element that follows the last element removed. Therefore, I tried to implement this:

```
std::vector<Customer*>::iterator j=customersList.begin();
while (j!=customersList.end()){
    customersList.erase(j);
    delete  *j;
}
```

is it o.k. or that it jumps 2 places by applying both erase and delete?

Comment: Why are you using pointers in the first place? `std::vector` allocates memory on the heap for you, you don't have to double that functionality.

Comment: Your loop cannot be correct. To exit the loop, `j` must be `customersList.end()`, which means you just dereferenced an iterator past the end of the container in the last iteration of the loop (and tried to `delete` the invalid pointer).

Comment: *it jumps 2 places* -- What do you mean by "jumps 2 places"?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I don't really understand what you means, which  functionality I double?

Comment: @Mr.OY -- Is there a reason to be using `std::vector<Customer*>` instead of `std::vector<Customer>`?  In any event, `j` becomes an invalid iterator, and then you're dereferencing the invalid iterator in the `delete`.  Why not a simple `std::for_each`, deleting each element, and then a single `clear()` statement?

Comment: @melpomene this is exactly why asked this question, does both of erase and delete make the iterator move to the next element?

Comment: @Mr. OY.  No, the iterator is not moved.  And `delete` knows nothing about iterators or iterator "movement", only pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie for the first question: "one jump" =the iterator move to the next element. hopefully that will explain what I mean by jumps 2 places.
for the second question: this is how I got the class, I think the reason is that the customers are in use in other places, and we don't want a copy of them. I will look up for what std::for_each saying because I don't know it. If you can explain the why of using it, it will wonderful.

Comment: @Mr.OY *the iterator move to the next element.* -- No, that is not correct.  On *returrn* of the `erase()`, you get the next iterator.  The `j` iterator does nothing.  Look at [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
please look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874533/9820561
It's saying that erase will make the iterator point to the next element. If I'm wrong, please tell me.

Comment: @Mr.OY -- You do see that your code fails to retrieve the return value of `erase`?  Maybe you missed that very important part of that answer.

Comment: @Mr.OY It's not saying that at all. Where do you see that?

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: @melpomene
yes I understood that I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop is not correct, since

1. you are invalidating the `j` iterator, and subsequent to that, issuing a `delete` call on the dereferenced, invalid iterator.
2. The `j` iterator is not incremented at all in that loop.

The easiest way to issue a `delete` and erase is a simple `std::for_each`, followed by a `vector::clear()`.

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
std::for_each(std::begin(customersList), std::end(customersList), [](Customer *c){delete c;});
customersList.clear();
```

or even simply:

```
for (Customer* c : customersList )
    delete c;
customersList.clear();
```

Comment: I'd argue that a plain `for` loop is even easier: `for (Customer *c : customersList) { delete c; }`

Comment: OK after understanding your code, I searched for some alternatives, tell me please if they are fine: first using for:                                           `for ( it = customersList.begin(); it != customersList.end(); )
        delete * it;
        it = customersList.erase(it); }`
 this is based on this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/991354/9820561 second try using while: 
`std::vector<Customer*>::iterator j=customersList.begin();
 while (j!=customersList.end()){ 
       delete *j;
       j=customersList.erase(j); }`