# Erasing first element while iterating with CGAL circulator

Tags: c++11, iterator, cgal, erase

I have a `CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>` and iterate over its vertices with CGAL vertex `circulator`. In the CGAL documentation, I cannot find any information about how to use the erase function correctly. 
Deleting in the middle isn't a problem, but how to handle the circulator, when the first element of it is deleted?

The naive [iterator erasing approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874533/9519322) works only in the first case, in the second case, the loop finished after one iteration.

```cpp
// p is of type CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>
auto ci = p.vertices_circulator();
auto start = ci;
int i = 0;

do {
  if (i == 0) {
    ci = p.erase(ci);
  } else {
    ++ci;
  }
  ++i;     
} while (ci != start);
```

This means `start` points to the formerly second element/now first element after erasing the first one?

How can I handle that case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `--start` right before the `do`  will work.

Comment: The loop doesn't terminate with this addition. The ```start``` pointer gets invalid after erasing (based on the default vector container class in ```CGAL::Polygon_2```?). But a solution that works is to replace ```start``` by ```--p.vertices_circulator()``` in the while condition. The disadvantage of this solution is that the last element has to be treated separately.