# How to use erase and iterator to delete a item in the two-dimension vector?

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, iterator

A two-dimension vector: (I want to go through vector and if I find the same name as "and", then delete or erase it, but why it can only work with it1 not it2? how to fix it?)

```
vector<Animals>numberOfAnimals(12);
vector<vector<Animals>>all(4,numberOfAnimals);

void delete_item(vector<vector<Animals>>&all,string ans)
{
    for (auto it1=all.begin();it1!=all.end();it1++)
    {
        for (auto it2=(*it1).begin();it2!=(*it1).end();it2++)
        {
            if ((*it2).getter_name()==ans)
            {
                all.erase(it1);  //no error
                all.erase(it2--); //error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The operator `->` can be used instead of `(*it).`. For example `it1->end()` instead of `(*it1).end()`.

Comment: `it1` is the iterator of `all` which is type `vector<vector<Animals>>` where-as `it2` is the iterator to a `vector<Animals>`; you want to do `it1->erase(it2)`

Comment: Related [Deleting elements from std::set while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874441/deleting-elements-from-stl-set-while-iterating).

Comment: `vector<Animals>` is probably not what you think it is. Each element in that vector holds _one_ `Animals`. What does the definition of `Animals` look like?

Answer (score 1):

`all` is a vector of vectors. `it1` is an iterator to `all`, so it can be passed to `all.erase`. `it1` refers to one of the vectors inside `all`.

`it2` is not an iterator to `all`, so it cannot be passed to `all.erase`. `it2` is an iterator to the vector `*it1` which is a vector of `Animals`. `it2` can be passed to `it1->erase`. `it2` refers to one of the `Animals` in `*it1`.

---

However, note that erasing an iterator to vector invalidates it. `it1` and `it2` are still used in the loop in a way that is not allowed to be done on an invalid iterator. Thus using `erase` in the loop without fixing the iterator has undefined behaviour.

The idiomatic way to selectively erase some elements of a container is erase-remove:

```
auto predicate = [&ans](const Animals& a) {
    return a.getter_name()==ans;
};
for(std::vector<Animals>& v : all) {
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), predicate));
}
```

This removes all of the `Animals` that match the predicate in each of the vectors within `all`.