# Is there any problem using a reference to a std::set key to erase itself?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
std::set<int> int_set = {1, 2, 3, 4};

for(const auto& key : int_set)
{
    if(key == 2)
    {
        int_set.erase(key);
        break;
    }
}
```

The code runs as expected, but is it safe?

It feels wrong to be using a reference to a key to erase itself from a set, as presumably once the erase has happened the reference is no longer valid.

Another code snippet with the same potential problem would be

```
std::set<int> int_set = {1, 2, 3, 4};
const auto& key  = *int_set.find(2);
int_set.erase(k);
```

Comment: I think my question is different to the similar question as I am interested in using a reference to erase from a set rather than an iterator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874441/deleting-elements-from-stdset-while-iterating

Comment: Is the presence of the `break;` statement an important part of your question? Without that, the iterator used (implicitly) in the `for` loop will become invalid after the call to `erase`.

Comment: How you have written it is fine. Like others have said though, after removing the `element` you've invalidated your `iterator`, but since you're breaking out of the loop you're fine. So yes, your code, as written, is safe. Just hope that no one comes along and removes that `break` statement at some point in the future.

Comment: So the reference to `key` will become invalid after the erase, but the erase itself using `key` is safe?

Comment: @KyleL Correct.

Comment: I agree with OP that this is not a duplicate of either target. The code could equally well have been written as: `const auto& k = *int_set.find(2); int_set.erase(k);` and the question (now 'answered' in the comments) is still meaningful and valid.

Comment: Yes, my query is related to the reference to the key being used, not the fact it is in a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is safe in the code provided since you `break` out of the loop without attempting to use the reference (`key`) again (nor implicitly advance the underlying iterator that for-each loops are implemented in terms of, which would happen if you did not `break`/`return`/`throw`/`exit()`/crash, when you looped back to the top of the loop) after the call to `erase`. `key` itself is only needed to find the element to remove; until that element is removed, it's valid, once it's removed, it's not used again by `erase` (it already found the element to erase, there's no possible use for it after that point).

If you tried to use `key` after the `erase`, you'd be using a dangling reference, invoking undefined behavior. Similarly, even allowing the loop to continue (implicitly advancing the underlying iterator) would be illegal; the iterator is invalid, and the implicit advancing of the iterator when you returned to the top of the loop would be equally invalid. The safe way to `erase` more than one element as you iterate would be to switch from for-each loops (that are convenient, but inflexible) to using iterators directly, so you can update them with the return value of `erase`, e.g.:

```
for(auto it = int_set.begin(); it != int_set.end(); /* Don't increment here */)
{
    if (predicate(*it)) {
        it = int_set.erase(it);  // In C++11 and higher, erase returns an iterator to the
                                 // element following the erased element so we can
                                 // seamlessly continue processing
                                                       
    } else {
        ++it;                    // Increment if we didn't erase anything
    }
}
```

Of course, as noted in the comments, if you only need to remove one element with a known value, the whole loop is pointless, being a slow (`O(n)` loop + `O(log n)` `erase`) way to spell:

```
int_set.erase(2);  // Returns 1 if 2 was in the set, 0 otherwise
```

which is a single `O(log n)` operation.

Comment: OP made it clear that the question is about using a *reference*, not an iterator. Your answer, while good, answers a different question. (Not my downvote though.)

Comment: @DevSolar: Well, the reference is a result of an implicit iterator in the for-each loop, which is why I mention it (alongside the reference). Without the `break`, you'd try to use that implicit iterator again. I'll clarify.

Comment: @DevSolar: Clarified. My goal was to make it clear that iterators are involved under the covers at all times, so it's not just that you can't use `key` again after the `erase`, the loop can't continue at all (because it involves an implicit `++hidden_iterator` where the hidden iterator is invalid as soon as `erase` occurs, and can't even be used to generate new iterators).