# Erase element in vector while iterating the same vector

Tags: c++, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Erasing from a std::vector while doing a for each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each)

I'm trying to implement vertice coloring according to this algorithm;

```
/*
Given G=(V,E):
Compute Degree(v) for all v in V.
Set uncolored = V sorted in decreasing order of Degree(v).
set currentColor = 0.
while there are uncolored nodes:
   set A=first element of uncolored
   remove A from uncolored
   set Color(A) = currentColor
   set coloredWithCurrent = {A}
   for each v in uncolored:
      if v is not adjacent to anything in coloredWithCurrent:
         set Color(v)=currentColor.
         add v to currentColor.
         remove v from uncolored.
      end if
   end for
   currentColor = currentColor + 1.
end while
*/
```

I don't understand "add v to currentColor." line but I supposed, it means assing currentColor to v. Therefore what is the "set"? Anyway the problem is erasing element in vector while iterating it. This is the code.

```
    vector<struct Uncolored> uc;
    vector<struct Colored> c;   

    int currentColor = 0;
    struct Colored A;
    struct Colored B;

    vector<struct Uncolored>::iterator it;
    vector<struct Uncolored>::iterator it2;
    vector<struct Colored>::iterator it3;

    for(it=uc.begin();it<uc.end();it++){

        A.id = (*it).id;        
        uc.erase(uc.begin());
        A.color = currentColor;
        c.push_back(A);

        for(it2=uc.begin();it2<uc.end();it2++) {
            it3=c.begin();
            while(it3 != c.end()) {
                if( adjacencyMatris[(*it2).id][(*it3).id] == 0 ) {
                    B.id = (*it2).id;       
                    it2 = uc.erase(it2);
                    B.color = currentColor;
                    c.push_back(B);
                }
                it3++;
            }
        }
        currentColor = currentColor + 1;
    }
```

I think `it2 = uc.erase(it2);` line is already general use but It gives run time error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In the line:

```
it2 = uc.erase(it2);
```

an element pointed by iterator `it2` is removed from the vector, elements are shifted in memory in order to fill that gap which invalidates `it2`. `it2` gets a new value and now points to the first element after the the removed one or the end of the vector (if removed element was the last one). This means that after erasing an element you should not advance `it2`. An alternative to proposed `remove-erase idiom` is a simple trick:

```
for(it2 = uc.begin(); it2 != uc.end();)
{
   ...   
   if(...)
   {
      it2 = uc.erase(it2); 
   }
   else
   {
      ++it2;
   }
   ...
}
```

You can read more about this [here](http://bojan-komazec.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/remove-selected-vector-elements-whilst.html).

**Edit:** 
Regarding your comment, you can use a flag to pass the information whether an element has been erased or not, and you can check it when you get out from the inner loop:

```
for(it2=uc.begin(); it2 != uc.end();)
{
   bool bErased = false;

   for(it3 = c.begin(); it3 != c.end(); ++it3)
   {
      if(adjacencyMatris[(*it2).id][(*it3).id] == 0 )
      {
         B.id = (*it2).id;
         it2 = uc.erase(it2);
         bErased = true;
         B.color = currentColor;
         c.push_back(B);
         break;
      }
   }

   if(!bErased)
      ++it2;
}
```

After you've erased an element from `uc` you need to break from the inner loop. In the next iteration of the outer loop you'll be able to access the next element in the `uc` through a valid iterator.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of working with `iterator` types, store an index into the `vector`. When you need an iterator--perhaps for passing into `erase`--you can say `begin() + myIndex` to generate an iterator.

This also makes the loop look more familiar, e.g.

```
for(ind=0; ind < uc.size(); ind++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

`vector::erase()` can [invalidate iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) pointing to the vector.

> This invalidates all iterator and references to position (or first) and its subsequent elements.

You need to add the result of `erase` to the iterator (it will point to the element just after the one erased) and use that consequently. Note that in

```
for(it=uc.begin();it<uc.end();++it){ 
  A.id = (*it).id;         
  uc.erase(uc.begin()); 
  ...
}
```

The iterator `it` is not valid after `uc.erase`, so subsequent ++ and use might result in runtime error.

Similarly, even though you assign the result of erase to `it2`, the call can invalidate `it`, which is not changed.

Your best bet is either to re-start your algorithm from the beginning after each `erase()`, or if you can alter it so that it can continue from the iterator returned by `erase`, do that to gain some efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the runtime error because `it2 = uc.erase(it2);` returns the iterator following the last removed element, so the `it2++` in `for(it2=uc.begin();it2<uc.end();it2++)` goes beyond the last element.

Try changing your if in:

```
if( adjacencyMatris[(*it2).id][(*it3).id] == 0 ) {
    B.id = (*it2).id;       
    uc.erase(it2);
    B.color = currentColor;
    c.push_back(B);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I have to continue iterating if iterator is not at the end.

Comment: In facts, the `break;` exits the while, but not the for. In this way the for loop makes it2++ and iterates with the next iterator.