# Vector subscript out of range with nested for loops

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

below is a snippet of code from a game I am writing in c++ with SFML.

```
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space)) {
        if (fireClock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() > 150) {
        Bullet vecBullet(Vector2f(player->getPosition()), player->angle);
        bulletVector.push_back(vecBullet);
        sleep(milliseconds(5));
        fireClock.restart();
    }
}

if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A)) {
    Enemy vecEnemy;
    enemyVector.push_back(vecEnemy);
}

for (int i = 0; i < bulletVector.size(); i++) {
    bulletVector[i].fire();
    bulletVector[i].draw();
}
for (int i = 0; i < enemyVector.size(); i++) {
    enemyVector[i].draw();
}

for (int i = 0; i < bulletVector.size(); i++) {
    if (bulletVector[i].getPosition().x > 2000 || bulletVector[i].getPosition().x < -100 ||
        bulletVector[i].getPosition().y > 1100 || bulletVector[i].getPosition().y < -100) {
        bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + i);
    }
}

for (int y = 0; y < bulletVector.size(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < enemyVector.size(); x++) {
        if (enemyVector.size() > 0 && bulletVector.size() > 0) {
            if (enemyVector[x].checkColl(Bullet(bulletVector[y]))) {
                bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + y);
                enemyVector.erase(enemyVector.begin() + x);
            }
        }
    }
}

cout << enemyVector.size() << " " << bulletVector.size() << endl;
```

What happens is that once the bullet is shot it hits the enemy and sometimes it crashes and throws the following error:

> program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll File: c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft
>   visualstudio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\vector
>   Line: 1806
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range

Any insights you can give me would be greatly appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: If `bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + y)` erases the last element, `bulletVector[y]` on the next iteration of the loop would access index out of bounds. In any case, even if index `y` is still valid, note that you effectively skip the element following the erased one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Igor Tandetnik pointed out, you could be [deleting an element from your array while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each) with `bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + y);`

There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927163/erase-element-in-vector-while-iterating-the-same-vector) of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713131/removing-item-from-vector-while-iterating/13102374) on SO about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each), and I probably won't explain it better.

---

I'd like to point something extra in your code. In this section:

```
for (int y = 0; y < bulletVector.size(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < enemyVector.size(); x++) {
        if (enemyVector.size() > 0 && bulletVector.size() > 0) {
            if (enemyVector[x].checkColl(Bullet(bulletVector[y]))) {
                bulletVector.erase(bulletVector.begin() + y);
                enemyVector.erase(enemyVector.begin() + x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where you look for collisions, this sentence is redundant:

`if (enemyVector.size() > 0 && bulletVector.size() > 0) {`

If any of both vectors is empty, at least one of the `for` loops won't iterate a single loop, so you could remove that check and save some computation and lines of code.

At that point, you ensure that both vectors have at least 1 element inside.