# How can i use iterator with vector erase?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector, erase

I don't know how to use iterator with erase.

I wanna use iterator to erase some elements.
But my code has some problem.

I guess value 'end' and code 'v.erase(it++)' doesn't work. I don't know why.
Is it right?

Please fix my code.

```
        vector<int> v = { 1,2,5,3,4 };
    auto it = v.begin();
    auto end = v.end();

    int erase_number = 5;

    while (it != end)
    {
        if (*it == erase_number)
        {
            
            v.erase(it++);
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Erasing an element invalidates iterators.

Comment: *Please fix my code.* -- `v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), erase_number), v.end());` -- There is no need for a `while` loop.

Comment: See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4645727/12002570) and [Erase element in vector while iterating the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927163/erase-element-in-vector-while-iterating-the-same-vector).

Answer (score 1):

This while loop

```
while (it != end)
{
    if (*it == erase_number)
    {
        
        v.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

is in whole incorrect because after erasing an element the iterator end will be invalid. You should write at least like

```
while (it != v.end() )
```

Also instead of this statement

```
v.erase(it++);
```

you have to write

```
it = v.erase( it );
```

Pay attention to that if your compiler supports C++ 20 then you can use the standard function `std::erase` like

```
std::erase( v, 5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove):

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), erase_number), vec.end());
```