# Vector of pointers Efficient/Correct Iteration

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

What is the correct way to iterate over a vector of pointers?
This prints "29" ten times, the desired output is "7, 8, 10, 15, 22, 50, 29"

Thanks a bunch!

Edit: Thanks for pointing out the initial errors. For some reason this example works even with multithreading but my code in my program doesn't. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int ints[] = { 1, 7, 8, 4, 5, 10, 15, 22, 50, 29 };
std::vector<int*> intptrs;
void iterate();

int main()
{
    for (int i : ints)
    {
        intptrs.push_back(&i);
    }
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    futures.push_back(std::async(iterate));
    futures.push_back(std::async(iterate));

    for (auto &f : futures)
    {
        f.get();
    }
    system("pause");
}

void iterate()
{
    for(std::vector<int*>::iterator it = intptrs.begin(); it != intptrs.end(); ++it;)
    {
        if (**it > 5)
        {
            std::cout << **it << std::endl;
            //Do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            delete (*it);
            it = intptrs.erase(it);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot `delete` what you did not `new`. Did you `new` those `int`? Then don't `delete` them. Just have `std::vector<int>` and use the "erase remove idiom".

Comment: Furthermore you are not storing pointers to the values in `ints`, but pointers to local variables created by the for loop which go out of scope after the loop.

Comment: Oops, I meant to be allocating them. Thanks for noticing

Comment: You're also incorrectly [erasing from the vector while iterating through it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each).

Comment: This code looks "better" but it is still inefficient and prone to errors. Why do you want to dynamically allocate `int`s so much?

Comment: I don't, of course. I was trying to provide a contrived example. In reality it would be a pointer to some other sort of data type.

Comment: Well if you want to ask a question about performance you need to give details about the types involved or you will get irrelevant advice.

Comment: Also, in general, avoid STL containers of naked pointers - in general it is better to use std smart pointers in the container. Easiest in most cases is probably to use std::vector<std::shared_ptr>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional idiom for iterating over a vector and removing some elements looks like this:

```
for(auto i = somevec.begin(); i != somevec.end();) {
    if (some condition) {
        i = somevec.erase(i);
    }
    else {++i;}
}
```

Notice that the `++i` isn't in the for loop header, it's in the body of the loop, and only happens if we don't erase. The iterator returned when you erase something from a vector is the iterator you would have gotten if you `++i`'d instead, so you'll end up skipping elements and incrementing `somevec.end()` if you write the code the way you wrote it initially.

(The reason your code is printing '29' is because you are invoking undefined behavior by dereferencing a pointer to a auto that has since been destroyed. In your implementation, it turns out that it's still got the last value it held.)

Comment: Awesome! Are there any other issues with the updated code? Or any improvements in efficiency?

Comment: Your use of async is incorrect. You're not synchronizing on the vector, so it's possible for one of the asynchronous instances of `iterate()` to erase an iterator while the other instance is doing something with the vector.

Comment: You might want to be clearer about what you actually want to do asynchronously; the approach you're currently taking is just going to result in a lock protecting the vector and both instances of iterate() happening in series. If the processing for each element of the vector can potentially take a long time, consider spinning up the thread for each non-erased element of the vector instead of running multiple threads over the one vector.

Comment: So, technically what I have is thread-safe but wont give any efficiency gains? Are you saying I should start a new thread to process each valid element as an optimization?

Comment: I'm saying it's not thread-safe, and the easiest way to make it thread-safe (using a mutex to access the vector) will give you only the efficiency gain that the main thread can do other things that don't touch the vector while the two calls to iterate() do things with the vector.

If you want to process multiple elements at the same time, shifting the asynchronous behavior to inside the loop (so something like `else {std::async(process, *i); ++i;}`) might be more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

An error is that

```
for (int i : ints)
{
    intptrs.push_back(&i);
}
```

should be

```
for (int &i : ints)
{
    intptrs.push_back(&i);
}
```

The reason? In the former, `i` is a local variable (which gets a copy of each array element in turn), so `&i` gives you a pointer to the local variable. You get a vector full of copies of the same pointer... and that pointer becomes invalid as soon as the loop ends. In the latter, you actually get references to the elements of the array.