# What is the safe way to iterate through a vector, and delete its certain elements

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, iterator

Is it possible to iterate in one single step through elements of a vector, while deleting some of the elements, to prevent repeated processing?
(I know the fragment is bogus, but illustrates what I want)

```
std::vector<MyRecord*>* BLV = GetVector();
for (std::vector<MyRecord*>::iterator it = BLV->begin(); it != BLV->end(); ++it)
{
  MyRecord* BL = *it;
  if(Selected)
  { 
    delete BL;
    BLV->erase(it);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each

Comment: Have you thought about using a vector of unique_ptr's and apply the erase-remove-idiom?

Comment: What's the relationship between `MyRecord` and `LinkRegisterRecord`?

Comment: @songyuanyao LinkRegisterRecord is the real name I use in my program. I forgot to rename it to my MWE. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

songyuanyao already gave you a nice answer: In short, you have to reset your iterator to the value returned by `erase`.

However, if applicable, I'd suggest using a vector of unique_ptr's and the erase-remove idiom (which is also more efficient, as it only moves the elements once).

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyRecord>>* BLV = GetVector();
BLV->erase(
    std::remove_if(BLV->begin(), BLV->end(), 
        [&](const std::unique_ptr<MyRecord>& rec) { return Selected; }
    ),
    BLV->end()
);
```

Answer (score 8):

Note [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) will invalidate the iterator to the element to be erased, and then `++it;` will lead to UB.

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

You can use the return value of `erase()`.

> Iterator following the last removed element. If the iterator pos refers to the last element, the end() iterator is returned.

then change the loop to

```
for (std::vector<MyRecord*>::iterator it = BLV->begin(); it != BLV->end(); )
{
  MyRecord* BL = *it;
  if(Selected)
  { 
    delete BL;
    it = BLV->erase(it);
  } else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
```