# Deleting element while iterating through nested vectors

Tags: c++

I was wondering how can I erase an element of a vector while keeping the iterator?Here I am looping through vector of vectors of type int :

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;
for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); row++) {
    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); col++) {
        if(*col==55)
        {
           //  col=row.erase(col); ?
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erasing from a std::vector while doing a for each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938838/erasing-from-a-stdvector-while-doing-a-for-each)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if there are multiple elements equal to 55, there would be multiple times of erase vector elements which will take much overhead to move elements.
A better solution is to follow [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to move all the qualified elements to the end of the vector, then erase them together in one time.
For example:

```
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;
for (row = vvi.begin(); row != vvi.end(); row++) {
     row->erase( std::remove( row->begin(), row->end(), 55), row->end());
}
```

std::remove will move all the element which equal to 55 to the end of the vector and return the iterator of the head of them. 
row->erase(iterator1, iterator2) will erase all the elements between 2 iterators.

And you don't need to care iterator anymore.

Comment: Hm , it says that remove is not in std?

Comment: try #include<algorithm>

Comment: Yes it worked out,I am testing it out not on ints, but on class Human for example and the class has property age ,I tried to replace 55 with row->age,however it is not recognized ,any ideas why?

Comment: In that case, you can try std::remove_if and customize the condition to remove element. like the example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: If you think the answer is useful, please vote for me :)

Comment: Yeah sure,can you lastly show what function should I create and pass to the erase methond in order to delete for example humans with age==20?

Comment: Stranegly I declared it in the class and instead of 55 I replaced it with isAge20,but the compiler says : 'isAge20' is not declared in the scope ,here is how it looks : row->erase( std::remove_if( row->begin(), row->end(), isAge20), row->end());