# C++ delete map of pointers: free() invalid size

Tags: c++, dictionary, free

I'm trying to delete pointers in a map, but it is giving an error at the `delete` part:

```
std::map<uint, std::vector<double>*> m;

std::map<uint, std::vector<double>*>::iterator it;
for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    delete it->second;
}
```

> *** Error in ...: free(): invalid size: 0x000000000a06ca30 ***

The vectors in the map definitely exist and contain a few values. I'm obviously missing something?

Edit: This is how I insert or update the vectors:

```
std::vector<double>* v = new std::vector<double>;
// add something to v
std::pair<std::map<uint, std::vector<double>*>::iterator, bool> ret = m.insert(std::pair<uint, std::vector<double>*>(i, v));
if(ret.second == false) {
    delete ret.first->second;
    ret.first->second = v;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your error is elsewhere

Comment: We need to see more code. In particular, we need to see how the map got its contents.

Comment: It might be that the vector exists, but how is it stored in the map? Between lines 1 and 5 of your code sample, nothing is stored in the map,

Comment: I added the insert part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you can test it here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef44f698821c9851

but you probably are doing something else in the middle, most probably double deleting those pointers - what causes such runtime error.

[after OP edit]

After seeing your edited question, I can say you most probably reuse the same pointers for various map keys. The solution is to set deleted pointer to nullptr as in following example:

```
std::map<uint, std::vector<double>*>::iterator it;
for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    auto ptr = it->second;
    for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        if ( it->second == ptr )
            it->second = nullptr;
    }
    delete ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't deleting the `map` but the `vector` here. Map is a container. You cannot delete it. Instead you can delete the objects in the map. If you just want to remove the objects in the map, you can use `map::erase`.

You can probably go through these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600567/how-can-i-delete-elements-of-a-stdmap-with-an-iterator)

Comment: I corrected the text. I'm trying to delete the pointers in the map, before the map is automatically destructed.

Comment: Then what you are doing is correct. Probably, put a null check before using `delete`

Comment: @dbrettschneider it looks like you might have the same pointer values in your map as values, this causes double deletions - and in the end runtime error. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are:

- trying to free a pointer that wasn't allocated by malloc
- or deleting an object that wasn't created by new
- or trying to free/delete object more than once

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use a boost::shared_ptr (or similar) for the contents of your vectors (boost::shared_ptr). Then you don't need to delete the contents, you can just erase the vector elements and the shared_ptr will free the memory for you without needing to use delete().

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<double> doublePtr;
std::map<uint, std::vector<doublePtr>> m;

std::map<uint, std::vector<doublePtr>>::iterator it;
for(it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    m.erase (it); // Erase the map element (i.e. the vector), this destroys the vector and all shared_ptrs then free their memory as no more references exist to them (in this sample)
}
```