# How to remove values from a QMap?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

Suppose I want to remove items according to some criterium. Let's say:

```
QMap<int, int> map;
```

and I want to remove all the items where value is an odd number. If I use an iterator:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
    if (it.value() % 2 == 1)
        map.remove(it.key());
```

This code is probably wrong, since the call of

```
map.remove(it.key())
```

invalidates the iterator. How can I do this without reseting the iterator after each removal?

Comment: This will help I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `QMap::erase` instead, which returns an iterator to the element following the one you just erased:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();)
    if (it.value() % 2 == 1)
        it = map.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
```

Another way is to use the *postfix increment* operator on the iterator:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();)
    if (it.value() % 2 == 1)
        map.erase(it++);
    else
        ++it;
```

Yet another way (and probably less efficient) is to use the STL `remove_copy_if` algorithm, followed by `swap`:

```
bool valueIsOdd(int value) {return value % 2 == 1;}

QMap<int,int> b;
std::remove_copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(),
                    std::inserter(b, b.end()),
                    &valueIsOdd);
a.swap(b);
```

I cannot test the last example at the moment.

Comment: You should only increment `it` if you didn't remove an element; otherwise, you'll miss the next element.

Comment: Or just use [QMutableMapIterator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutablemapiterator.html#details).

Answer (score 5):

You would be better off using the more STL-like [`erase`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qmap.html#erase) function:

- It takes an iterator as an argument, and so doesn't waste time searching for the element by its key when you already know where it is;
- It returns an iterator to the next element, so you can carry on iterating afterwards.

Using this, you can implement your loop correctly as:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); /* don't increment here */) {
    if (it.value() % 2 == 1) {
        it = map.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

I think you could get the same result from `map.remove((it++).key())`, but that would be both slower and messier than `erase`.