# How to dump unordered map while adding and erasing elements to it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unordered-map

I want to dump the keys of an unordered_map while being able to simultaneously add and erase elements. It takes 4 seconds to dump entirely, it's too long. Is it possible to dump in separate thread, like this:

```
while (1) {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
    if(iter!=map.end()){
        x=iter->first
        iter++;    
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

    do_this(x);  // this takes time to complete
}
```

while in the main thread I have:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
map.erase(iter);
```

Does the erase method of unordered map make problem, since the iterator will be invalid after erasing.

Is there any other safe way to dump in parallel?

Comment: What exactly does "do_this" do?

Comment: @Mats: It doesn't matter.

Comment: I was looking for "is there some other way to solve the 'it takes 4 seconds' ", rather than a direct answer to the question.

Comment: `do_this` does fstream operations. so I can't make it faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `unordered_map` (and associative containers in general), the `erase()` member function does *not* invalidate iterators and references to other elements than the removed one(s).

However, here you may be erasing an element and invalidate iterators to it while your loop holds an iterator to that element: for instance, if you happen erase the element which is referenced by the next iterator that is going to be dereferenced in your loop.

Hence, you need to take care that the element you are removing is *not* referenced by the iterator you are going to process in the next loop of your `while` cycle:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
if (i != iter)
{
    map.erase(i);
}
else
{
    // Maybe store in a queue of elements to be removed after the loop is done
}
```

Where `iter` is the iterator variable used in the loop.

Comment: What if iter is erased by the other thread during the unsynced do_this() call - it will be invalidated, and the next increment will cause UB.

Comment: @jmetcalfe: I assumed from the question's text that `do_this()` processes the element but does not modify the map. Now I'm a bit confused though, as to *where* the `do_this()` is supposed to be

Comment: I don't think do_this() matters, just the fact that you are holding an iterator while not holding the mutex, so the other thread can come along and erase that iter.

Comment: @jmetcalfe: Well, `do_this()` is not holding an iterator, but an element. My assumption is that `do_this()` does not work with the map, so it won't hold iterators.

Comment: The loop around do_this() is still holding the iterator, and incrementing it in the next iteration

Comment: @jmetcalfe: `do_this()` does not hold an iterator, and the loop before it just loops through the end. Which is what makes me wonder as to where `do_this()` is actually *meant* to be. The loop can't interleave with `erase()` because of the mutex, only `do_this()` can. But then again, `do_this()` does not hold an iterator.

Comment: do_this doesn't hold an iterator, but the loop around it does. It holds it while do_this is called. if the iterator is invalidated at this point, do_this will succeed without issue, but in the next loop iteration the held iterator will be invalid. The loop can interleave because do_this is within the loop

Comment: @jmetcalfe: I don't know why, but for some reason I was reading the `if` as a `while`. Let me re-read it.

Comment: It's a bit confusing (and loops infinitely in it's current form...) :)

Comment: @jmetcalfe: right, the iterator could be invalidated. I will edit my answer

Comment: +1 for the new solution. Good idea. Only thing to add is you need to make sure that type of x (and the key) is simple i.e. not a reference, pointer or similar as that is obviously also invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

See: [What happens if you call erase() on a map element while iterating from begin to end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to)

Since you increment the iterator before calling the `do_this` method which calls `erase` it will not cause any troubles.

Just a thought: With your current algorithm I don't think that you need the mutex at all.

Comment: My understanding was that it was a separate thread calling erase, not the do_this call, which does the dumping?

Answer (score 1):

You could get some (but not all - this really just allows you to interleave the operations so that the erase does not have to wait the entire 4 secs) of the desired parellelism by iterating buckets rather than iterating elements. This would be safe as long as the bucket count is not reduced

i.e.

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex ); 
size_t count = map.bucket_count();
pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );

for(size_t i = 0; i<count; ++i){
  pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
  for(auto it = map.begin(i); it != map.end(i); ++i)
    do_this(it->first);
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
}
```

if you wanted to pull the do_this out of the mutex you would need to accumulate the values in some other structure

**Another suggestion**, depending on exactly how this map is used elsewhere, is that you could just swap the element to some known invalid value instead of erasing, then have the thread which is doing the dumping/do_this do the actual erase when it sees this value.