# C++ erase vowels in list<string>

Tags: c++, string, list, c++11

I have a university assignment to write a function that in a list of strings all vowels detected have to be removed, and after that, list needs to be sorted from largest to smallest string.

What I've tried is similar to list of `int`'s to define iterator, de-reference it and compare with characters with `if` and do this for all vowels, and that doesn't work.

What I need to change in the code below? I first tried to write in `main()` to test if it would compile. Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    string x;
    list<string> vowel;

    while (cin >> x)
        vowel.push_back(x);

    list<string>::iterator k;

    for(auto k=vowel.begin(); k!=vowel.end(); k++)
        if(*k == 'A' || *k =='a' || ...) // for every letter that is a vowel
            vowel.erase(*k);

    vowel.sort();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Do you mean erase all vowels from a list of **characters** (which is a string) or find and erase all vowels in a list of strings? can you give an example of the expected behavior. (Because I think you meant the first one.)

Comment: University assignment? Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

To check if character is vowel you can `std::find` it in `std::vector` of all vowels:

```
static inline bool isVowel( char ch)
{
        static const std::string vowels("aeiouEAIOU");
        return vowels.end() != std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch);
}
```

usage:

```
std::assert( isVowel( 'a') == true);
```

---

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::string x;
    std::vector< std::string> vowel;
    vowel.push_back( "a");
    vowel.push_back( "b");
    vowel.push_back( "c");
    vowel.push_back( "d");
    vowel.push_back( "e");
    vowel.push_back( "f");

    std::vector< std::string>::iterator k;

    for( k = vowel.begin(); k != vowel.end();)
      if( isVowel( *((*k).c_str())))
          k = vowel.erase(k);
      else
          ++k;

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Use std::remove_if with functor

This is usually faster than using function. Application operator can be easily inlined.

```
struct isVowel_{
    std::string& vowels;
    isVowel_( std::string& s) : vowels( s) {}
    bool operator()( std::string c) const {
        return vowels.end() != std::find(vowels.begin(), 
                                                  vowels.end(), *(c.c_str()));
    }
};

int main()  {
  std::vector<std::string> vowel;
  vowel.push_back("a");
  vowel.push_back("b");
  vowel.push_back("c");
  vowel.push_back("d");
  vowel.push_back("e");
  vowel.push_back("f");

  std::vector<std::string>::iterator k;
  std::string vowels("aeiouEAIOU");

  k = std::remove_if( vowel.begin(), vowel.end(), isVowel_( vowels));

  vowel.erase( k, vowel.end());  // erases the unspecified values and reduces
                                 // the physical size of the container to match
                                 // its new logical size
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but using a predicate would be even nicer :) +1, anyway.

Comment: true, has been added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems with your code that you'll likely need to sort out:

## 1. Naming

The name `vowel` isn't a good name for the list of input strings. Something like

```
std::list<std::string> inputStringList
```

would be better.

## 2. Iterator declarations

You're declaring the variable `k` twice. Once here:

```
list<string>::iterator k;
```

and again here:

```
for(auto k=vowel.begin(); k!=vowel.end(); k++)
```

You should only declare the variable once. Get rid of the first declaration.

## 3. String Comparison

In this piece of code:

```
for(auto k=vowel.begin(); k!=vowel.end(); k++)
    if(*k == 'A' || *k =='a' || ...) // for every letter that is a vowel
        vowel.erase(*k);
```

You're comparing the value at `k`, which is a `std::string`, to 'A', which is a `char`. Don't do this. You should compare strings to strings, or chars to chars, but don't mix and match. Either change your declaration of `vowel` to `std::list<char>`, or change your if statement to compare strings instead

```
if (*k == "A" || ...)
    //    ^-^--- Note use of double-quotes for a string literal.
```

## 4. Undefined Behaviour

When you erase each string from the list, you're engaging [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
vowel.erase(*k);
```

Once you have erased the string from the list, your iterator has become invalid, but you proceed to use it again in the next iteration of the `for` loop (`k++`). You *might* get away with it, but I would expect not.

Bear in mind that even if it DID work (and it doesn't), you'd end up skipping over characters you've not checked, because the strings that are after the erased string all get shifted up one.

Better would be to use a `while` loop to iterate and erase. Like this:

```
auto iter = myList.begin();
const auto endIter = myList.end();

while (iter != endIter)
{
    if (some test here)
      myList.erase(iter++);
    else
      ++iter;
}
```

Why this works can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to/263958).