# Erase other elements of std::map while iterating

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a map with following key value pairs.
{(a,P),(b,Q),(c,R),(d,S),...(g,Z)}

I'm iterating this map and at each element I take a branch which access this same map and erase an element of the map if a condition is met.
Simply put, it is possible that while the main iterator is at (b.Q) , the branching function can erase (d,S).

Is this valid.? Or will this seg fault.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps you should post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the iterator invalidation rules:

[std::map::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other
>   references and iterators are not affected.

So as long as you don't use the iterator where you erased, you are good.

Comment: So what happens when the main function "reaches" (d,S) when it was already deleted ?

Comment: After you erase an element (e.g. (d, S)) that element is not part of the container anymore. You will never reach it again by iterating through the container. CARE: if you have an iterator to (d, S) obtained before the erase,  that iterator is invalidated, so you can't use it anymore.

Comment: But it says invalidation doesn't happen in C++ 03.. And I do get a seg fault with "Double Free or Corruption"

Comment: @PasanW  Ofc it happens. Read again. Quoting from the answer: «Erasing elements in a map does not invalidate any iterators. (**apart from iterators on the element that was deleted**)»

Comment: @PasanW If you get a runtime error then you either still use the iterator to the erased element, or you have another bug in your code. Post another question with a [MCVE] exhibiting the error.