# Different behavior observed upon doing erase(iterator) on vector and map

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, stdmap, erase

A simple [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

```
std::vector<int> integers;
integers.push_back(10);
integers.push_back(11);    
cout  << "Before: " << integers.size();  //prints 2
```

I tried using 3 different versions of code to erase each element one by one C++5.1 and C++14

Version 1:

```
for( std::vector<int>::iterator it = integers.begin() ; it != integers.end() ; )
{
  cout << "\nVal: " << *it;
  it = integers.erase(it); 
}

cout << "\nAfter: " << integers.size();
```

Output: [**[Expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to)**]

```
Before: 2
Val: 10
Val: 11
After: 0
```

Version 2 in C++14:

```
for( std::vector<int>::iterator it1, it = integers.begin() ; it != integers.end() ; )
{
    cout << "\nVal: " << *it;
    it1 = std::next(it);
    integers.erase(it);
    it = it1;
}
```

Output: [**Unexpected**]

```
Before: 2
Val: 10
After: 1
```

While for [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), version 2 works as expected:

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(10, 11));
    m.insert(make_pair(12, 13));
    cout  << "Before: " << m.size();

    for( std::map<int, int>::iterator it1, it = m.begin() ; it != m.end() ; )
    {
        cout << "\nVal:  " << it->first << ", " << it->second;
        it1 = std::next(it);
        m.erase(it);
        it = it1;
    }
    cout << "\nAfter: " << m.size();
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Before: 2
Val:  10, 11
Val:  12, 13
After: 0
```

Even this works :

```
for( std::map<int, int>::iterator it1, it = m.begin() ; it != m.end() ; )
{
    cout << "\nVal:  " << it->first << ", " << it->second;
    m.erase(it++);
}
```

**Why version 2 works on std::map but not on std::vector?**

Comment: Where in the standard is it stated that `map<>::erase(it)` and `vector<>::erase(it)` have to exhibit the same behavior with the resulting iterator? The only thing I am aware of is that the first version is guaranteed to work in a generic way.

Comment: `map::erase` doesn't support version 1. Yes standard doesn't state that, but from developer's points of view, one can easily make mistake while using `version 2` with `vector`.

Comment: I just tried it, with `it =  m.erase(it);` and no use of `it1`, I get `After: 0`

Comment: You *could* click on [`erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) on the page you linked to and read about iterator invalidation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `std::vector` iterators are invalidated after erasing an element while for associative containers (23.2.4 Associative container)

> 9 The insert and emplace members shall not aﬀect the validity of
>   iterators and references to the container, and the **erase members
>   shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased
>   elements**.

Comment: Yes I read it in comments section http://stackoverflow.com/a/263958/1465553; given by @Loki. But I am not sure why it is decided that way. Any sane reason to do that.

Comment: @SauravSahu In the vector the elements after the erased element are moved left one position.

Comment: Ok...that reason really makes sense.

Comment: @SauravSahu In general internally elements of a vector are represented like elements of a dynamically allocated array.