# Unordered map erase method storing temporary variable

Tags: c++, unordered-map

For a `unordered_map` `erase()`, I have seen a few threads suggesting different methods for doing it (like getting the next element from the return of `erase()`).  However, I haven't seen anybody suggesting the following. So, I was wondering if there is some issue with this approach:

```
for (auto it1 = map.begin(); it1 != map.end(); )
{
   auto it2 = it1++; //it2 assigned before it1 incremented
   map.erase(it2);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `map.erase(it1);` ?

Comment: @feverdream this invalidates `it1` and the subsequent iteration of the loop would be undefined. The canonical way is `it1 = map.erase(it1)`.

Comment: @feverdream because that would invalidate `it1` ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this method and it was suggested indeed for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to

Comment: Also correct is simply `map.erase(it1++);` No need for a second variable. You do have to understand that the iterator is incremented before erase is called, which is something that people do get confused about.

Comment: Great.  Thanks Slava.  Good to know there is no issue with this approach.

Comment: Thanks John.  That's a good suggestion

Answer (score 3):

This approach works fine. [`std::unordered_map::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) only invalidates the iterator to the erased element (i.e. `it2`), the aforehand incremented iterator `it1` remains valid.

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other iterators and references are not invalidated.