# stl::map erase vs std::vector erase behave differently

Tags: c++, stl

```
 class CSensor
 {
    public:
    CSensor(int nVal1,char* pVal2,unsigned int nVal3);
    CSensor(const CSensor& refMessage);
    const CSensor& operator=(const CSensor& refMessage);
   ~CSensor(void);
   private:
   int m_nVal1;
   char* m_pVal2;   
   unsigned int m_nVal3;
 };

 // vector erase

 std::vector<CSensor> SensorList;
 CSensor obj1(1,"Test1",10);
 SensorList.push_back(obj1);
 CSensor obj2(2,"Test2",11);
 SensorList.push_back(obj2);
 CSensor obj3(3,"Test3",12);
 SensorList.push_back(obj3);

 SensorList.erase (SensorList.begin()+1);



// map erase
    std::map<int ,CSensor> ListSensor;
CSensor obj11(1,"Test1",10);    
CSensor obj12(2,"Test2",11);
CSensor obj13(3,"Test3",12);

ListSensor.insert(std::pair<int,CSensor>(1,obj11));
ListSensor.insert(std::pair<int,CSensor>(2,obj12));
ListSensor.insert(std::pair<int,CSensor>(3,obj13));

ListSensor.erase(2);
```

I debugged both the case.
   In both the cases i am deleting the second element.In case of vector
   it is copying 3 element to 2nd poition and than it it deleting the 3 rd location.

So when u say

```
   List.erase (List.begin()+1);
```

it is calling assignment operator(CSensor=) and then calling destructor.

In case of map when i do

```
   ListSensor.erase(2);
```

it only calls the destructor.

I have gone through [STL vector vs map erase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714/stl-vector-vs-map-erase).
  It talks Iterator,couldn't explain the behavior.

My question is why erase behaves differently for these two STL container??

Comment: Because they are different containers? Why would you expect them to work in exactly the same way? Why would they then both exist?!

Comment: C++ is a case sensitive language, and it helps if while communicating we are somehow precise to this respect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a behaviour of `.erase` *per se*, but a consequence of how each respective container works.

#### Deleting from a vector

When you delete from a vector <sup>(`List` is a *really* poor name for a vector, btw)</sup>, its contents must be shuffled along to fill the gap because the elements of a vector are always stored *contiguously* in memory.

This is generally done by copying (or moving) elements then chopping off the remainder:

- Vector elements in memory:

  ```
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ```
- Erase 'e':

  ```
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d |   | f | g | h | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ```
- Fill the gap by copying/moving across:

  ```
                     <--
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d | f | f | g | h | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

                         <--
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d | f | g | g | h | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

                             <--
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d | f | g | h | h | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

                                 <--
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d | f | g | h | i | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ```
- Resize the container:

  ```
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | a | b | c | d | f | g | h | i |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ```

---

#### Deleting from a map

This is not the case for a map, whose contents are not necessarily stored contiguously in memory (in fact, the complexity requirements mean it's almost always a tree structure filled with pointers to discontiguous data).

Comment: I agree @Tomalak Geret'kal.I just want to expand the discussion . Is Data Structure  the reason for Invalid iterator for vector where as in map doesn't invalidate the iterator.

Comment: @Chris_vr: That question doesn't really make sense. Both vector and map are types of containers, so "Data Structure" (as you put it) is relevant to _everything_ we're discussing.

Comment: very nicely illustrated answer :)

Comment: @Chris_vr: (However, yes, the differences in the way elements are stored in the respective containers _contributes_ to the different [iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) for each.)

Comment: this is a good explanation about memory internals but it doesn't answer the question about calling the operator=...

Comment: @Pedro: Yes it does. `operator=` is invoked to shuffle those elements along... "Fill the gap by copying/moving across"

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal ok ok, you're right! you don't like to be contradicted, specially when you're right ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This is one reason to have different containers!

The vector has to copy the elements following the eased element to cover the "hole" that it left. Otherwise the elements wouldn't be contiguous anymore.

The map holds its elements in a tree structure and just has to adjust some pointers to rebalance the tree.

To the vector's defense: Copying a couple of elements might be cheaper than allocating tree nodes separately and keeping the tree balanced. There are always tradeoffs!

Comment: Minor nitpick; the standard doesn't mandate a tree for `std::map`. It just sets requirements that sort of lead you there in a sane implementation.